# Show list of data on my firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I'm trying to show the data's that i have inputted in my `activity`, but the problem is i don't have any idea how to, I'm at lost on the data snapshot one. I'm trying to like only show the name and email

My database 
[image: Database]

my code and progress so far

```
public class AdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout mdrawerl;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mtoggle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Accounts").child("Users");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            collectName((Map<String,Object>)dataSnapshot.getValue());
        }
        private void collectName(Map<String, Object> value) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }                         
    });
```

reference that i used [How to get all child's data in firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965731/how-to-get-all-childs-data-in-firebase-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Create a model class that will hold the objects of user. In your case it would be

```
public class User {
private String email;
private String name;
private int type;

public User() {
}

public User(String email, String name, int type) {
    this.email= email;
    this.name= name;
    this.type= type;
}
}
```

2 - Create a `ArrayList` that will hold items of `User`

````
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList();
            for (DataSnapshot child :
                            dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = child.getValue(User.class);
                userList.add(user )
            }
           //Here you have all user you can pass ```userList``` to your method furthur
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }                         
    });
````

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello can i ask what do you mean by "Here you have all user you can pass ```userList``` to your method furthur" ?

Comment: what i meant there, was that you will have all the data that you have under ```User``` node into ```userList``` you can pass userList to any of your method as param and perform your own use-case to it.

Comment: Oh Hello sir thanks for replying, umm sorry to say this but i don't understand :(( if possible can you provide me some samples?

Comment: What you don't understand?