# How to get the current user profile image and name from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Below is my Firebase structure image,

**Firebase Structure**

[image]

I will like to use the name and profile image of user for my Second Activity.

Here how I did for my another app,

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();
String name = user.getDisplayName();
```

And I later used the `name` in my `TextView` to use the current user name but here it didn't worked and besides I also needed the profile image too.

So, How do I get the user image and name from above Firebase structure image to my Second activity layout `TextView` and `ImageView` and set the default text name and image if it returns null.

I tried below but it didn't worked to

```
public void setUserData(String name, String image) {

    ImageView userimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    userimage.setImageURI(userimage);
}
```

Comment: For user data retrieve: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38966753/5272951  For download image from storage: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

Comment: You are using firestore

Answer (score 0):

Your url is a string not Uri. So, you need to fetch the image from the given url.

You can use AsyncTask like:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953632/how-to-set-image-from-url-for-imageview%20this%20might%20help)

or use Glide library to make async calls. [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Answer (score 0):

get userRecord by calling  getUserAsync(String uid)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/UserRecord