# Android Firebase getting child values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have ở Firebase Database structure looks like this. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Mpl.jpg)
I want to get the data from red area. I have tried this code:

```
ref.child("shop").child("orders").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    for (DataSnapshot temp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Receipt temp2 = temp.getValue(Receipt.class);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The Receipt temp2 return null. Please someone can tell me how i can get that data. Thanks in advance
Edit 1:
Here is my Receipt class:

```
public class Receipt {
    private String name;
    private String province;
    private String district;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String style_payment;
    private int state;
    private int tmp;
    private int cost;
    private int total;
    private ArrayList<ProductInReceipt> productList;

    public Receipt(){}
    public Receipt(String name, String province, String district, String address, String phoneNumber, int state, ArrayList<ProductInReceipt> productList,String style_payment,
                   int tmp,int cost, int total) {
        this.name = name;
        this.province = province;
        this.district = district;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.state = state;
        this.productList = productList;
        this.style_payment = style_payment;
        this.tmp = tmp;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all child's data in firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965731/how-to-get-all-childs-data-in-firebase-database)

Comment: can you post your Receipt class code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your data structure is:

```
orders
  $uid
    $orderid
      ...
```

Your code reads all of `/orders` and then loops over the results. That means that you're looping over users. So at the very least you're missing a loop in your code.

```
ref.child("shop").child("orders").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        for (DataSnapshot receiptSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Receipt receipt = receiptSnapshot.getValue(Receipt.class);
        }
      }
    }
    ...
```