# Apps-Script. How to collect all data from all record? Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-apps-script

Image of database

[image]

So that's my database, and I wanna collect all `alamat` from all record i have, `diki` and `rizky`

Here is my code

```
var optList = {"method" : "get"};
var recordName = "diki";

var rsltList = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://martabak-bot.firebaseio.com/" + recordName + "/.json", optList );
var importdb = JSON.parse(rsltList);
var posting= (importdb.alamat);
```

So far I can collect Diki's `alamat` and put it on `posting` variable.

So if I wanna collect all `alamat`, what should I do?
Based on this question : [How to get all child's data in firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965731/how-to-get-all-childs-data-in-firebase-database/56482438#56482438)

Is this `datasnapshot` works for me too?
But I don't see it finished with stored to a variable.

Thanks for the help and answer, I really a beginner in JS. Thank you.

Comment: Firebase documentation talks about [collections of documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) and how to [filter by keys](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#filtering-by-key) ; simplying `fetch()`ing `https://martabak-bot.firebaseio.com/.json` will return your full DB

Comment: @Altigraph actually since the day u comment this and till now i read it again and again.
and doing testing but it looks like the answer of my question :(

Comment: how to up this question.. please i need some help :( its a weeks since i ask this

Answer (score 0):

I think you should denormalizing your data, for example to create something like

```
martabak-bot/
  alamat/
    diki: Tiban
    rizki: Taman
    ...
```

so you can retrieve them with

`curl 'https://martabak-bot.firebaseio.com/alamat.json?print=pretty'`

see [Denormalizing Your Data is Normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html)

Comment: So what if i only wanna collect diki's data?

Comment: You already have diki's data as you mentioned above right? So just replaca `/alamat.json` with `/diki.json` no?

Comment: no no, i mean, if u said i need to change the databse form like u tell me to. i will not able to collect diki's data..

Comment: Not change but denormalize data.